# Destroy/reset singleton in laravel way

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, singleton, destroy

```
public function register() {
    $this->app->singleton('Qwerty', function ($app) {
        return new QwertyManager();
    });
}
```

This is what my singleton class looks like now i want to reset the singleton object or destroy its instance via laravel. I am using 5.3

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can call **forgetInstance()** on the service container to remove it. As the doc's say, this method can be used to `Remove a resolved instance from the instance cache`.

```
App::forgetInstance('Querty');
```

Next time you'll try to get an instance of this service from the container, it will be re-created using the function you provided in the **singleton()** method.